# Can't import firestore from firebase_admin

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I tried using google cloud for firebase and I encountered this problem while trying to set it up. I don't really know what the problem is.

```
!pip install firebase-admin
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import choice, randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('digitalworld.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

This is the error I received:

```
ContextualVersionConflictTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e4e1fc936b08> in <module>()
      6 import firebase_admin
      7 from firebase_admin import credentials
----> 8 from firebase_admin import firestore
      9 
     10 cred = credentials.Certificate('digitalworld.json')

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 try:
---> 22     from google.cloud import firestore # pylint: disable=import-error,no-name-in-module
     23     existing = globals().keys()
     24     for key, value in firestore.__dict__.items():

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
     19 from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import ArrayRemove
     20 from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import ArrayUnion

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py in <module> ()
     17 from pkg_resources import get_distribution
     18 
---> 19 __version__ = get_distribution("google-cloud-firestore").version
     20 
     21 from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import types

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in get_distribution(dist)
    479         dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
    480     if isinstance(dist, Requirement):
--> 481         dist = get_provider(dist)
    482     if not isinstance(dist, Distribution):
    483         raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    355     """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
    356     if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 357         return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
    358     try:
    359         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in require(self, *requirements)
    898         included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
    899         """
--> 900         needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    901 
    902         for dist in needed:

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    789                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    790                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 791                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    792 
    793             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 0.1.4 (/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0'), set(['google-cloud-firestore']))
```

I have tried installing several things, like grpcio, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-firestore, but I'm not really sure what the problem is. Sorry rookie coder here.

Comment: doesnt that error mean that you have `google-api-core` version `0.1.4` but `google-cloud-firestore` wants a version between `2.0.0dev` and `1.14.0`? so install `google-api-core==1.14.0`

Comment: I just tried doing that, but it still returned the same error

Comment: The solution that @Alex mentioned should work, as it is indeed what is happening, try to run `pip install --upgrade pip` to get the current version of pip and make sure this is not a bug with pip itself.

Comment: Did upgrading pip fixed the issue?

Comment: Has anyone fixed this yet? I am getting the same error